# The *args and **kwds in python super call

Tags: python

I am trying to understand the use of `*args` and `**kwds` when creating subclasses in Python.

I want to understand why this code behaves the way it does. If I leave out the `*args` and `**kwds` in a call to `super().__init__`, I get some strange argument unpacking.

Here is my test case:

```py
class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self, moves, num_legs):
        self.moves = moves
        self.num_legs = num_legs

    def describe(self):
        print "Moves :{} , num_legs : {}".format(self.moves, self.num_legs)

class Snake(Animal):
    def __init__(self, poisonous, *args, **kwds):
        self.poisonous = poisonous
        print "I am poisonous:{}".format(self.poisonous)
        # This next line is key. You have to use *args , **kwds.
        # But here I have deliberately used the incorrect form,
        # `args` and `kwds`, and am suprised at what it does.
        super(Snake, self).__init__(args, kwds)
```

Now, when I create instances of the Snake subclass, which contains the erroneous call to `super(…).__init__` (where I use `args` and `kwds` instead of `*args` and `**kwds`), I get some interesting “argument unpacking”.

```py
s1 = Snake(False, moves=True, num_legs=0)
s2 = Snake(poisonous=False, moves=True, num_legs=1)
s3 = Snake(False, True, 3)
s1.describe()
s2.describe()
s3.describe()
```

What I get is:

```py
Moves :() , num_legs : {'moves': True, 'num_legs': 0}
Moves :() , num_legs : {'moves': True, 'num_legs': 1}
Moves :(True, 3) , num_legs : {}
```

So why is it that in `s1` and `s2`, `__init__` assumes that `moves = True` and `num_legs = 0` or `1` are keyword arguments, and sets the `num_legs` to a dict?

In `s3`, it unpacks both of the variables to `moves` (in class `Animal`) as a tuple.

---

I stumbled into this as I was trying to understand argument unpacking. Sorry in advance—I don't know how to frame this question any better.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In `Snake.__init__`, `args` is a tuple of all positional arguments after `poisonous` and `kwds` is a dict of all the keyword arguments apart from `poisonous`. By calling

```
super(Snake,self).__init__(args,kwds)
```

you assign `args` to `moves` and `kwds` to `num_legs` in `Animal.__init__`. That’s exactly what you are seeing in your output.

The first two calls don’t have any positional arguments apart from `poisonous`, so `args` and consequential `moves` is an empty tuple. The third call has no keyword arguments, so `kwds` and consequential `num_legs` is an empty dict.

Answer (score 7):

In short: `def __init__(self,poisonous,*args,**kwds):` means: capture positional arguments in a tuple `args` and keyword arguments in a dictionary `kwds`. Similarly, `super(Snake,self).__init__(*args, **kwds)` means: unpack the tuple `args` and the dictionary `kwds` into arguments so that they're passed separately to `__init__`.

If you don't use the `*` and `**` then you're passing `args` and `kwds` as they are, which means you're getting a tuple and a dictionary.

---

As you've said, you'd need to write:

```
super(Snake,self).__init__(*args, **kwds)
```

to properly pack / unpack the arguments. In your current code you're not packing / unpacking the arguments so it sets `num_legs` to a dictionary as that's what `kwds` is at the moment.

---

If you don't give the arguments names then they're positional arguments. Hence `Snake(False,True,3)` are all positional arguments.

If you do give the arguments names then they're keyword arguments: `Snake(poisonous=False,moves=True,num_legs=1)`.

In the first case you're combining both one positional argument and two keyword arguments: `Snake(False,moves=True,num_legs=0)`.

Comment: Read the comment before the line `super(Snake,self).__init__(args,kwds)`

Comment: @flornquake: that's fair. In that case you're indeed getting the behaviour as it is.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed explanation it is much appreciated. Till I read your answer I did not understand that the Snake init was essentially setting the *args and the **keywords to behave the  way they were. In combination with above answer I understand now that not unpacking the args in the super call makes them behave as positional arguments with their arg-ness or "keyword/dict-ness" dictated by the Snake __init__(poisonous, *args , **kwds) statement.

Answer (score 1):

A variability is nicer and more intuitive than this `Snake(False, True, 3)`:

```
Snake("Python", constrictor=True, poisonous=False)
Animal("Snail")    # Snail has a foot but no leg. Defaults are good for it.
# Cobra eat other snakes, including poisonous, fast attacks, snake fights.
Snake("Indian cobra", moves=True, poisonous=True)
Animal("Myriapod", num_legs=750)  # Changes for an idividual after every molting.
```

Oh, really exciting question about Python, not only about programming. :)

It is a good idea to have the most individual parameters on the first places, that are common for all subclasses, like the universal "self" itself is. The next very common is a name like in this example.

If you believe that your classes will be never modified and they will be used everytimes with all implemented parameters and you will never make a mistake in the correct order, you need not any variability. You can continue to use fixed positional parameters as you are used. This assumption is frequently not fulfilled. Tomorrow will nobody remember what should be the first *False* and the second *True* without seeing it together with keywords.

If you need to call your class with fixed positional parameters by `Snake(False, True, 3)`  you can not use `**kwds` for any of these parameters.

A)
Let we now expect it that your example `Snake(False, True, 3)` is a required test case. Then you can't use  ****kwds** for anything of your **positional parameters** `(poisonous, moves, num_legs)`. You have only these four possibilities of implementation __init__ header: (none good enough)

```
# the most fragile solution - easy extensible, not easy to observe the order
class Snake(Animal):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.poisonous = args.pop[0]
        # or better ...pop[-1]  that allows adding new parameters to the end
        super(Snake,self).__init__(*args)
        # now is args undefined if ancestors could eat parts from it but
        # everything is in self

# the most naive solution - easy readable, not easy extensible because not DRY
class Snake(Animal):
    def __init__(self, poisonous, moves, num_legs):
        self.poisonous = poisonous
        super(Snake,self).__init__(moves, num_legs)

# anythig between them combines disadvantages of both previous
class Snake(Animal):
    def __init__(self, poisonous, *args):
        self.poisonous = poisonous
        super(Snake,self).__init__(*args)
class Snake(Animal):
    def __init__(self, poisonous, moves, *args):
        self.poisonous = poisonous
        super(Snake,self).__init__(moves, *args)
```

.
B)
**Keyword parameters** are more robust because some their errors can be automatically reported.
Expect that you redefine Animal to increase its variablility:

```
class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self,name, moves=True, num_legs=None):
        self.name = name
        self.moves = moves
        self.num_legs = num_legs

# The recommended Snail  !
class Snake(Animal):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        """Snake: Implements.. (Docs important, otherwise real keywords not seen in help)

        kwds:                (only what defined here)
            poisonous:  Bla bla. default=True
            constrictor:  Bla bla bla. default=False
        """
        # A copy of kwds can be created, if manipulation with original is prohibited.
        self.poisonous = kwds.pop('poisonous', True)  # default: poisonous snake
        self.constrictor = kwds.pop('constrictor', False)
        # OK. This reports error if some keyword is misspelled and will not be consumed.
        super(Snake,self).__init__(*args, **kwds)

# This Snake is more readable, but its descendants would be more complicated,
# otherwise is possible: "TypeError: got multiple values for keyword argument 'xy'".
class Snake(Animal):
    def __init__(self, name, poisonous=True, constrictor=False, *args, **kwds):
        self.poisonous = poisonous
        self.constrictor = constrictor
        super(Snake,self).__init__(name, *args, **kwds)
```

Now you have a big variability and the order of keyword arguments is not important.

Comment: Thanks for your example--I agree my example is very contrived with a 4 legged snake etc. Thanks for the pointer to flexible ways of doing it. Also for "pop(key[, default])"
If key is in the dictionary, remove it and return its value, else return default. If default is not given and key is not in the dictionary, a KeyError is raised.

Comment: Also I like the recommended Snail way ..only problem is most 3rd party modules dont have a <code>__doc__ /docstring</code>..so I always found it confusing to see all __init__ with *args **kwds. But with the doc it is so clean and easy to read

Comment: I accepted your edit. Hmm, docs. Many people go directly to the source because they do not believe the find anything or they do not know `!help(some_obj)` in the debugger. (without exclamation mark can't be displayed help to the object in Pdb) With too much looking into the source I would use many undocumented - unstable internals.